# How do I mix multiple audio streams into a single recorded stream with Java?

Tags: java, audio, javafx, mixer, tritonus

Using Java Sound, Tritonus and JavaFX, how can I intercept data sent to the speakers and record it as a file?  For example, I want to mix JavaFX media player audio streams (and/or Java Sound audio streams) into a single "wav" file in the same way a recording studio environment might do it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Java Sound API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html)